# Is it possible to have two conditions in pandas .ix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if there is a way to have more than one conditions with .ix. More specifically, what I'm trying to do is change this:

```
In [66]: df_test
Out[66]: 
      A          B         C         D         E
0 -0.013863      False -0.546036  0.373015  1.002579
1  1.275009          2  0.447672 -0.393775 -1.509525
2 -0.517209          0  0.543322  2.434393  0.348002
3  1.768921          0 -1.015705  1.121779  1.548792
4  0.575418        NaN -1.803939  0.099772  0.508620
5  0.722897   0.519641  0.435199 -0.059685 -0.585716
```

where:

```
In [67]: type(df_test.iloc[0,1])
Out[67]: bool

In [68]: type(df_test.iloc[1,1])
Out[68]: str

In [69]: type(df_test.iloc[2,1])
Out[69]: str

In [70]: type(df_test.iloc[3,1])
Out[70]: int
```

to this:

```
      A          B         C         D         E
0 -0.013863        NaN -0.546036  0.373015  1.002579
1  1.275009          2  0.447672 -0.393775 -1.509525
2 -0.517209          0  0.543322  2.434393  0.348002
3  1.768921          0 -1.015705  1.121779  1.548792
4  0.575418        NaN -1.803939  0.099772  0.508620
5  0.722897   0.519641  0.435199 -0.059685 -0.585716
```

It seems that items in positions `[0,1]` and `[3,1]` are both == `False` and as a result, when I try `df_test.ix[df_test.B == False, 'B'] = np.nan` both of these items are turned to `NaN`.

When I try `df_test.ix[df_test.B == False and type(df_test.B) == bool, 'B'] = np.nan` I get the following error: `KeyError: 'cannot use a single bool to index into setitem'`

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
In [133]: df_test
Out[133]: 
      A         B         C         D         E
0 -0.013863     False         1  0.373015  1.002579
1  1.275009         2  0.447672 -0.393775 -1.509525
2 -0.517209         0         3  2.434393  0.348002
3  1.768921         0       NaN  1.121779  1.548792
4  0.575418       NaN  -1.80394  0.099772  0.508620
5  0.722897  0.519641  0.435199 -0.059685 -0.585716
...

In [134]: df_test.dtypes
Out[134]: 
A    float64
B     object
C     object
D    float64
E    float64
dtype: object

In [139]: type(df_test['B'][0])
Out[139]: bool

In [140]: type(df_test['B'][1])
Out[140]: str

In [141]: type(df_test['B'][2])
Out[141]: str

In [142]: type(df_test['B'][3])
Out[142]: int

In [143]: type(df_test['B'][4])
Out[143]: float

In [144]: df_test['B'] == False
Out[144]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

**EDIT2**
See below how this is reproduced

```
In [226]: df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))

In [227]: df_test
Out[227]: 
      A         B         C         D         E
0  0.609775  0.205708 -0.015081  2.096414  0.121245
1  1.223234 -1.299398  1.238649  0.216846 -0.789828
2  0.446873  1.734404 -0.675568 -1.203400  0.053905
3  0.286693 -0.080294 -0.115739 -0.195039  0.400201
4  0.519230  1.939370 -0.424466  0.102137 -0.724420

In [228]: df_test.iloc[0,1] = False

In [229]: df_test.iloc[1,1] = '0'

In [230]: df_test.iloc[2,1] = 0

In [231]: df_test.iloc[3,1] = '2'

In [232]: df_test.B == False
Out[232]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this as your code works as expected, if you did `df['B'] == False` you will get a boolean Series and see that just the first entry is `True`

Comment: Not if the type of the `0` is int, and it is. `False == 0`. This is why I was trying to introduce the type check in there as well to avoid treating `0` as `False`.

Comment: Sorry I still can't reproduce this, edit your question showing what `df['B'] == False` returns

Comment: @EdChum Could it be some configuration that is off? I have to admit that it does not seem strange at all to me as `bool(False) == int(0)` produces `True`. I cannot see how the type check is unnecessary really.

Comment: What version of pandas is this? Can you post raw data and code to load a representative Series that reproduces this error

Comment: In [223]: print('Python version ' + sys.version)
    Python version 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]

    In [224]: print('Pandas version: ' + pd.__version__)
    Pandas version: 0.18.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109071/discussion-between-thanos-and-edchum).

Comment: This looks like a bug can you post it on github

Comment: @EdChum Thanks for the help, I have created an issue in the github project.

Comment: I guess that this is expected behaviour then, surprising but it follows what numpy does

Comment: Yes, the issue was closed as a non-bug indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code does what you want. It maps values that are `False` to `np.nan`:

```
df_test['B'] = df_test['B'].map(lambda x:np.nan if x == False else x)
```

Edit:

A better way is just

```
df[df == False] = np.nan
```

**Actual solution**

After some sweat, it seems that multiple conditions are possible with `map()` and the below worked fine:

```
df_test['B'] = df_test['B'].map(lambda x: np.nan if ((type(x) == bool) & (x == False)) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not really address the type matching issue. Also, your second suggestion is not limited to column 'B', but it have an effect on all columns of the dataframe.

Comment: Right, this worked on a clipboard copy of your dataframe, which doesn't result in different types. Is it possible to use the map-technique with multiple conditions though, checking for type as well as x == False?

Comment: Yes, multiple conditions inside `map()` seem to work fine. I'm suggesting the edit.